# ASP.NET MVC kills my IIS - too many request

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I facing a big issuse. I've build software that now over 100 users use at once.
Since than my MVC ASP.NET Application is dying. The IIS Crashes over 30-40 times a day.

[image]
**i dont have any recursively code**

Main Probleme is that all users fetch a boolean which tell's them if they need to get new data.
That fetch-http method is called 1-5 times a second from diffrent users.

But the SQL-Reader is slower than the request made.

```
Error Message: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

or

```
Error Message: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 97
```

My method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("fetch")]
public IHttpActionResult fetch()
{
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con);
   string sql = "SELECT whentime FROM did_datachange WHERE ux_admin_id = " + id;

   connection.Open();
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
   {
      using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               if (reader.FieldCount == 1)
                   dateTime = reader.GetDateTime(0);
               }
           }
   }
   connection.Close();

   ....following code...
}
```

i know that **lock** cloud solve that problem, but using lock slows down the code significantly. what can i do?

Comment: Several suggestions for possible improvements. Enable Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) in the connection string. Use a `using` statement for your `SqlConnection`. Fix what looks like a SQL Injection vulnerability in your query caused by your use of string concatenation. Make the method `async` and use whatever `...Async()` equivalents of methods like `Read()`, `Open()` etc are available to whatever version of .NET Framework you're using and `await` them. Scale up or scale out your hardware. Code your clients to check for updates less frequently.

Comment: MARS doenst not work for me. If i add it to the connection string the application wont start

Comment: i will try to make it async

Comment: You can think of using cache to safeguard the database from large number of queries... Do you see any error when you use `MARS`? can you share that error?

Comment: `if (reader.FieldCount == 1)` is not necessary... if you are expecting only one value from the query execution, you should not use reader...  you should use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method to avoid looping and risk of already opened data reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was bad code (multi threading that threw alot of execeptions)